Alpha compositing in fixed point (0xff is not 1.0)
I'm writing some code (intended for use from both C and C++) that does alpha compositing using integer math (fixed point), and I'm coming across the problem that 0xff isn't quite 1.0. This is particularly problematic in the alpha channel. For example (0xff * 0xff) >> 8 equals 0xfe. So if you have a white pixel with alpha 0xff and RGB 0xff, and you try to premultiply your alpha channel into the color channels, you end up with 0xfe in the RGB channels, so you no longer really have white.
Here are some example functions that do alpha premultiplication and then alpha-compositing with premultiplied alpha, both of which have some variant of this problem. These are for little endian RGBA/BGRA, let's ignore byte order issues for now:
uint32_t premultiply_alpha(uint32_t color)
{
        uint32_t alpha = ((color>>24) & 0xff);
        uint32_t rb = color & 0xff00ffU;
        uint32_t g  = color & 0x00ff00U;

        rb = (rb * alpha) >> 8;
        g  = (g  * alpha) >> 8;

        return (color & 0xff000000) | (rb & 0xff00ff) | (g & 0x00ff00);
}

uint32_t rgb_blend(uint32_t background, uint32_t color)
{
        uint32_t alpha = color>>24;
        uint32_t rb = background & 0xff00ffU;
        uint32_t  g = background & 0x00ff00U;
        rb = (color & 0xff00ff) + ((0xff - alpha) * rb >> 8);
        g  = (color & 0x00ff00) + ((0xff - alpha) * g  >> 8);

        uint32_t dest_alpha = background>>24;
        dest_alpha = alpha + dest_alpha - ((alpha*dest_alpha) >> 8);
        dest_alpha = dest_alpha < 255 ? dest_alpha : 255;

        return  (dest_alpha << 24) | (rb & 0xff00ff) | (g & 0x00ff00);
}


The first function has the exact issue I described in prose above, and the second one has a similar problem in the expression (0xff - alpha), which can correctly express zero, but not 1.0.
How do people usually handle this without making a round trip through floating point? I'm sure people have already studied and solved this issue. Thanks.

Edit: as pointed out in the helpful comment by John, the issue is that >> 8 is equivalent to division by 0x100, not 0xff. Therefore, replacing the shift by / 0xff solves the problem. However, since the divisor is constant, the compiler will avoid a div instruction using the trick from Chapter 10 of Hacker's Delight (I confirmed that GCC does this even without optimization turned on). It seems empirically that it's not safe to process r and b in the same register, as I was doing here, in the presence of that optimization. I'm still interested in hearing if there are "standard" solutions to this / what other people tend to do.

I guess the problem is >> 8 which is equivalent to / 0x100. What happens if you try / 0xFF instead of >> 8?

People handle it differently in the distinct languages. Pick only one in the tags.

@john thanks, you're totally right. I'm still interested in hearing whether this is the standard way people approach this or not (if there is a standard way), but this is clearly one valid way.

3CxEZiVlQ, the example code I posted is completely reasonable in both C and C++, and I'd be interested in solutions leveraging the features of either one.

the example code I posted is completely reasonable in both C and C++ -- unsigned -- In C++, the data types in  would be used to guarantee the bitness of the type.

I think that's actually true in C as well, but in practice my compiler happily takes it in either language. You're technically right of course, just like the endianness of the machine is technically a factor for very standards-oriented code, but the question here is really about fixed point techniques and using one-byte alpha/color channels, the code is for illustrative purposes.
